# How to organize h:selectOneMenu with items in sublists within root list on JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is there a way to organize h:selectOneMenu with items in sublists within another list on JSF framework?

Example;

```
<LIST - 1>
    <list 1>
        <item 1 - name: a>
        <item 2 - name: b>
    <list 2>
        <item 1 - name: c>
    <list 3>
        <item 1 - name: d>
        <item 2 - name: e>
```

Instead of using duplicated objects, I want to get and display names of items (a, b, c, d, e in h:selectOneMenu) that are already obtained from DB. I already know that a list and items of it can be presented easily on h:selectOneMenu. However, how can I present items in sublists within another list?

All feedback appreciated!

Comment: Are you using primefaces?

Comment: Create method with signature `public List<SelectItem>`, fill list with data from DB and use it in `h:selectOneMenu`: <f:selectItems value="#{bean.methodName}" />

Comment: @JosefE. , I do not have used in this project yet, however there is no obstacle not to use it. Which tag do you offer in primefaces? Is there a way to do with JSF tags?

Comment: @VasilLukach , I already know the solution you refered. However, I already have the list that contains some inner-lists and items. Creating new list object (ex./ new List<SelectItem>();) and adding items from the big list, that I already have, seem like duplicating objects. At least, new list object I create is an extra and redundant object in this situation. Hence, I try to find a solution with the list I already have.

Comment: If you don't want to use 100% working solution, try put a few `<f:selectItems />` with existing lists from your menu (reuse existing lists)

Comment: @VasilLukach , can you give an example to reach the solution of this problem with <f:selectItems/>?

Answer (score 0):

If sublists were built dynamically on server side, then you can reuse its in combined list. See example:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="mix">
    <f:selectItems value="#{referenceLists.dobMonths}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{referenceLists.dobDays}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.dobYears}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```